# Longest increasing subsequence using 2-3 tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

While preparing for my data structures final I came across this problem:

A - a given array of integers of length n.

Propose data structure which supports the following operations:

**Init(A)** - initialisation of the structure given the array A. Worst case complexity: O(nlogn).
**LengthOfLongest()** - returns the length of the longest monotonically increasing s of A (elements). Worst case complexity: O(1).

I know that it is a well known problem, and I'm aware of the relevant wiki article. However the solution provided there is not intuitive to me.

I was given a hint that this problem can be solved as well with 2-3 rank tree for instance.

Can someone explain me the solution using 2-3 tree?

Example:
For array A = {10,9,11,8,12,7,13}
The longest subsequence is {10, 11, 12, 13} and its length is 4.